# Loading CSV files into an ArrayList

Tags: java, csv, bufferedreader

I have to load data from different CSV files. At the moment, I have this. It works well, but basically I have to load the data from different files into different arrays (one is Books, the other one is customers account). I don't want to repeat the code. I want to make this code (LoadingData) reusable for every CSV file I have to upload. Any ideas on how I can work this out. Here is how my class "Loading" looks so far.

```java
public class LoadingData {

    ArrayList<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();

    //ArrayList<Reader> readers = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public void Loading(String fileName){
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))){
        
            
            String currentLine;
            while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null){
                
                // separating the data by the comma
                String[] detailed = currentLine.split(",");

                // skiping the first line since it has only titles and no the data I want to store
                if(detailed[0].equals("id"))
                    continue;
                
                //Storing data in variables

                String id = detailed[0];
                String title = detailed[3];
                String firstName = detailed[1];
                String lastName = detailed [2];
                String genre = detailed [4];  
                
                //adding the data to the arraylist

                books.add(new Book(id, title, firstName, lastName, genre));
               
            }
            
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        

    }}
}
```

Comment: Add a parameter of type [java.lang.Class](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html) to method `loading`. Then you can instantiate the class using reflection and the data read from the CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class LoadingData {

        public LoadingData(ArrayList<Book> books, String fileName){
            this.file = file;
            this.books = books;
        }


        public ArrayList<Book> Loading(this.fileName){
            try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))){


                String currentLine;
                while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null){

                    // separating the data by the comma
                    String[] detailed = currentLine.split(",");

                    // skiping the first line since it has only titles and no the data I want to store
                    if(detailed[0].equals("id"))
                        continue;

                    //Storing data in variables

                    String id = detailed[0];
                    String title = detailed[3];
                    String firstName = detailed[1];
                    String lastName = detailed [2];
                    String genre = detailed [4];

                    //adding the data to the arraylist

                    books.add(new Book(id, title, firstName, lastName, genre));

                }

            } catch (IOException ioe) {

                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
            return books;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want a single `loading` method that can handle any CSV file that contains an unknown number of fields in each line of the file.

The below code uses [reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) to create objects and adds them to a generic [List](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html).

For demonstration purposes, I wrote a minimal implementation of class `Book` and a sample CSV file which I named `books.csv`.

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class LoadingData {
    List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public void loading(String fileName, Class<?> theClass) {
        Constructor<?>[] ctors = theClass.getConstructors();
        Constructor<?> ctor = ctors[0];
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {
            String currentLine;
            boolean first = true;
            while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null){
                String[] detailed = currentLine.split(",");
                if (first) {
                    first = false;
                    continue;
                }
                Object instance = ctor.newInstance((Object[]) detailed);
                list.add(instance);
            }
        }
        catch (IllegalAccessException    |
               IllegalArgumentException  |
               InstantiationException    |
               InvocationTargetException |
               IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LoadingData ld = new LoadingData();
        ld.loading("books.csv", Book.class);
        System.out.println(ld.list);
    }
}

class Book {
    String id;
    String title;
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String genre;

    public Book(String id, String title, String firstName, String lastName, String genre) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.genre = genre;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s by %s %s (%s)", title, firstName, lastName, genre);
    }
}
```

Here is the contents of file `books.csv`

```
ID,TITLE,FIRST NAME,LAST NAME,GENRE
1,Moby Dick,Herman,Melville,Adventure
2,To Kill a Mockingbird,Harper,Lee,Fiction
```

Here is the output when running the above code.

```
[Moby Dick by Herman Melville (Adventure), To Kill a Mockingbird by Harper Lee (Fiction)]
```

Comment: Thank you for! that is exactly what I want. Although I am trying to figured out why it's only loads two books and I am getting this errors. Check following comments....

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:64)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
 at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
 at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)

Comment: at librarysystem.LoadingData.loading(LoadingData.java:31)
 at librarysystem.LibrarySystem.main(LibrarySystem.java:19)
[Book{id=140a3d7e-a417-4c2b-96fe-32f9a2732693, title=Kennan, authorFN=Stowers, authorLN=Tarzan's Magic Fountain, genre=Action|Adventure|Fantasy|Romance}
, Book{id=b4eb8f48-2bbb-46bf-b836-017f9372c463, title=Tripp, authorFN=Wiltshier, authorLN=Possession, genre=Drama|Horror|Mystery|Romance|Thriller}
]
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: @DavidEspiño you should update your question (or ask a new question). Note that my code does not check the validity of the contents of the CSV file. It is not a production-ready solution. It demonstrates a method you can use to achieve your goal. It is a proof-of-concept (POC). I think you should post a new question. Include your latest code as well as the sample contents of your CSV file including the line in the file that is causing the `IllegalArgumentException`